fpdf does not show rows generated by a for loop in the document Python
I have the following problem in this code, I emphasize that the code worked before, I updated some libraries and it stopped working, the problem is when the for loop is executed, it does not show the rows in the pdf document with the data that is extracted from the DataBase, here I am going to leave all the code:
from fpdf import FPDF
from flet import *
from datetime import datetime
from controlador.conexion import *
from controlador.mensajes import *
import pathlib
import logica
import os
import shutil

class Pdf(FPDF):
    def __init__(self):
         self.Header()

def Header(self):
    self.idPedidos = []
    resultadoPrecios = db.obtenerCostosCilindros()
    #self.resultadosiDPedidos = logica.consulta("SELECT pedidos.id FROM pedidos JOIN jefesF_Cilindros ON pedidos.jefesF_Cilindros_id = jefesF_Cilindros.id JOIN jefesf ON jefesF_Cilindros.jefesf_id = jefesf.id JOIN cilindros ON jefesF_Cilindros.cilindros_id = cilindros.id JOIN empresas ON cilindros.empresas_id = empresas.id JOIN tamano ON cilindros.tamano_id = tamano.id JOIN picos ON cilindros.picos_id = picos.id WHERE liderCalle_id =? AND pedidos.fecha IS NULL", [logica.datoUser[0][0]])
    
    #------------------Definir tipo de hoja----------------
    self.pdf = FPDF(orientation="P", unit="mm", format="A4")
    self.pdf.add_page()

    #---------------------Insertar Logo-------------------------------

    self.pdf.image(f"{logica.rutaactual}\img\clap.png", x = 45, y = 5, w = 120, h = 35)
    #self.pdf.image("SistemaClapFlet\img\clap.png", x = 45, y = 5, w = 120, h = 35)
    self.pdf.rect(x = 0, y = 45, w = 210, h = 0)

    #---------------------Título del Pdf---------------------------
    self.fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    self.pdf.set_font("Times", "B", 25)
    self.pdf.set_y(55)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 0, h = 15, txt = "Reporte de cilindros", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 0, ln=1)
    self.pdf.set_font("Times", "U", 12)
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"{mensaje.datosUsuarioLista[0][1]} {mensaje.datosUsuarioLista[0][2]}", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 0)
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"{mensaje.datosUsuarioLista[0][3]}", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 0)
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"Altagracia de Orituco {self.fecha}", border = 0, align = "C", fill = 0)
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"Precio Unitario:       Pequeñas={resultadoPrecios[0][0]}Bs    Medianas={resultadoPrecios[1][0]}Bs    Regulares={resultadoPrecios[2][0]}Bs    Grandes={resultadoPrecios[3][0]}Bs", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 0)
    
    self.Body()

def Body(self):

    #---------------------Tabla-------------------------------
    self.pdf.set_font("Times", "", 14)
    self.pdf.set_y(115)
    self.pdf.set_fill_color(r = 239, g = 71, b = 71)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Cédula", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Nombre", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Apellido", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Empresa", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1)
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Pico", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1) 
    self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Tamaño", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1) 
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 27, h = 15, txt = "Agregado", border = 1, align = "C", fill = 1)

    #----------------------------------Lista-------------------------------------
    
    c = 0

    contP = 0
    contM = 0
    contR = 0
    contG = 0

    valorP = 0
    valorM = 0
    valorR = 0
    valorG = 0

    totalP = 0
    totalM = 0
    totalG = 0
    totalR = 0

    self.informacion = db.obtenerJornadaArchivo(mensaje.datosUsuarioLista[0][0])
    print(self.informacion)
    #-----------------------------Cliclo For-----------------------------------------
    for ids, ci, nom, ape, emp, pic, tamn, cos, fech in self.informacion:
        print(ids, ci, nom, ape, emp, pic, tamn, cos, fech)
        if tamn == "Pequeña":
            contP = contP + 1
            totalP = valorP + cos
            valorP = totalP

        elif tamn == "Mediana":
            contM = contM + 1
            totalM = valorM + cos
            valorM = totalM

        elif tamn == "Regular":
            contR = contR + 1
            totalR = valorR + cos
            valorR = totalR

        elif tamn == "Grande":
            contG = contG + 1
            totalG = valorG + cos
            valorG = totalG
        else: pass
        

        c+=1
        if(c%2==0):self.pdf.set_fill_color(r = 209, g = 209, b = 209)
        else:self.pdf.set_fill_color(r = 255, g = 255, b = 255)

        self.pdf.set_font("Times", "", 12)
        self.pdf.set_draw_color(r = 239, g = 71, b = 71)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(ci), border = "TBL", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(nom), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(ape), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(emp), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(pic), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1) 
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(tamn), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1) 
        self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(fech), border = "TBR", align = "C", fill = 1)

        self.idPedidos.append(ids)

    totalVenta = totalP + totalM + totalR + totalG
    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"Cantidad:       Pequeñas={contP}    Medianas={contM}    Regulares={contR}    Grandes={contG} Monto Total: {totalVenta}Bs", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 2)

    self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = f"Observaciones:", align = "C", border = 0, fill = 3)

    self.Footer()

def Footer(self):
    rutaActual = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
    nombreArchivo = f'jornada_venta_de_gas_{mensaje.datosUsuarioLista[0][1]}_{self.fecha}.pdf'
    rutaEscritorio = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), rf'Desktop\Reportes')

    self.fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

    if os.path.exists(rutaEscritorio) == True:
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(rutaEscritorio)

    
    #--------------------------Pie de pagina------------------------------------

    self.pdf.output(rf'{rutaActual}\Reportes\{nombreArchivo}')
    self.pdf.output(rf'{rutaEscritorio}\{nombreArchivo}')

    db.guardarRutasArchivos(rf'{rutaActual}\Reportes\{nombreArchivo}', self.fecha)
    resultadoIdArchivo = db.obtenerIdArchivo(rf"{rutaActual}\Reportes\{nombreArchivo}", self.fecha)


    for i in self.idPedidos:
        db.asignarIdArchivo(resultadoIdArchivo[0][0], i)
    self.idPedidos.clear()

I even tested the code without extracting data from the DB but providing it with already defined ones and still nothing is shown, this is the part of the code that gives me problems
if(c%2==0):self.pdf.set_fill_color(r = 209, g = 209, b = 209)
        else:self.pdf.set_fill_color(r = 255, g = 255, b = 255)

        self.pdf.set_font("Times", "", 12)
        self.pdf.set_draw_color(r = 239, g = 71, b = 71)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(ci), border = "TBL", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(nom), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(ape), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(emp), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1)
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(pic), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1) 
        self.pdf.cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(tamn), border = "TB", align = "C", fill = 1) 
        self.pdf.multi_cell(w = 27, h = 10, txt = str(fech), border = "TBR", align = "C", fill = 1)

And this is how the pdfs are coming out


You're drawing all the rows at Y=115, aren't you?  I don't see you advancing the row.

It used to work like this, how do you think I should modify it?

It could not have worked like this.  Did you change the last cell call to multi_cell?  If you pass ln=1 to cell, that causes the start of a new line after the cell, but multi_cell can't do that.  I suggest you add self.pdf.ln() after the multi_cell call.

add ln=1 in the last cell end of header and in the last cell in for loop with that code now all the data are written out side the page

@DiegoMarin the variable db where is imported or created in your code? Is it possible that the instruction db.obtenerJornadaArchivo(...) gets an empty list?
